# Friendly id, Friendly is reserved

Tags: rspec, model, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

Um - Most confusing validation error ever, considering I am not even using the word `Friendly` how ever my model for roles looks like this:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :role, presence: true

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :role, use: [:slugged, :history]
end
```

(Yes I have the proper migration .. Lets look at those too ... )

```
class AddSlugToRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :roles, :slug, :string
    add_index :roles, :slug
  end
end
```

Now lets create a factory girl

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :adminRole, :class => 'Role' do
    role "Admin"
  end

  factory :userRole, :class => 'Role' do
    role "User"
  end  
end
```

Finally lets write a spec and make sure we can create roles:

```
  context "Validation checks" do
    it "validates a role object" do
      FactoryGirl.build(:adminRole).should be_valid
    end
  end
```

We then get a failing message of:

```
  1) Role Validation checks validates a role object
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.build(:adminRole).should be_valid
       expected #<Role id: nil, role: "Admin", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, slug: "admin"> to be valid, but got errors: Friendly is reserved
     # ./spec/models/role_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm sorry what? Where am I using the word `Friendly`? Oh thats right, I'm not. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Turns of the use of the word `admin` is considered reserved. theres also a ton of other words like

`config.reserved_words = %w(new edit index session login logout users admin
    stylesheets assets javascripts images)`

that are also reserved.